# $H$ not closed under addition due to inverses, but closed under inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a fairly basic question.

Problem from my text:

> $G=\left \langle \mathbb{R}^2 ,+\right\rangle, H=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2>0\}. $ Determine whether H is a subgroup of G.

It's easy to show that $H$ is closed under inverse $\left((-x)^2+(-y)^2>0\right)$.

When testing whether $H$ is closed under addition, though, I checked:
$$(x_1+x_2)^2+(y_1+y_2)^2\overset{?}{>}0$$
The answer seems clear to me: No, $H$ is not closed on addition because of the instance $(x+x^{-1})^2+(y+y^{-1})=0$.

What seemed odd to me is that $H$ is closed under inverses but is not closed under addition **when $h\in H$ is equal to its own inverse**. Is this a correct conclusion of the problem?

Comment: What's the identity?

Comment: How is $h \in H$ equal to its own inverse. Let $h = (x,y)$. Then the inverse of $h$ is $(-x,-y)$.

Comment: Notice that for $(x, y) \in \Bbb{R}^2$, the condition $x^2 + y^2 > 0$ is equivalent to $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$.  Do you see how that's a problem for $H$ being a group?

Comment: I didn't try to find it. Looking at it now, it cannot be what I automatically assumed ($e=(0,0)$) because $(0,0)\not\in H$. How do I solve the equation $(x,y)+(e_1,e_2)=(x,y)$ without getting the $(0,0)$ which is not in $H$? My instincts tell me that $H$ is not a group at all.

Comment: Looks like all these comments are saying the same thing I just realized--$H$ is not a group! (and therefore not a subgroup of $G$). Thank you! I feel equal amounts of gratitude for the help and embarrassment for overlooking that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have proven that $H$ is closed under inverses. To prove that $H$ is *not* closed under addition, consider $(x, y)+(-x, -y)$.

(Considering this product actually gives you two reasons why your subset isn't a subgroup! Also, you should realise that this subset is precisely $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(0, 0)$...)